# How to integrate app with facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, integrate

I made a quiz app using wordpress using a quiz plugin so that, the work could be done easily. I do not have any knowledge about how to integrate that app that I've made with facebook. Right now I've just kept the app on my localhost.

Do I need to add some API's or something like that?  I have not handled AJAX and all that before but I do have knowledge about php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should clarify a bit about how do you want your app integrate with Facebook:

1) You want your quiz application as an on-Facebook canvas page application (which seems to be the case here):

1. [Register an application on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). The guide here is fairly easy to follow.
2. Read the basics about [canvas Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)
3. Learn about [OAuth 2.0 authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) with Facebook. This step is optional since there is a [good PHP library](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) for Facebook. But I think it will saves you time afterwards.
4. Use [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) for Facebook.

2) You want to use your own website, just add "login with Facebook" function (to record high scores, for example):

You should check [Facebook integration for website](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). It's not too different from the first case.

I just give you the starting place. If there's something that is not clear enough, feel free to drop a more detailed comment.

Comment: Thanks, I want my quiz application as on - facebook canvas page application. I have done the first 3 steps. I am just facing problem in using the php sdk. I cannot understand what i've to do next. Please elaborate.

Comment: @VJ41: you need to config your facebook app (at step 1) to point to your server link (using settings in "On Facebook" menu). Then download the php sdk, look at some sample code and use it to deal with the oauth process of Facebook.

Comment: @VJ41: if you have more questions about technical problems, feel free to add more details.